# How to append a database to an excutable

Tags: c, sqlite

According to the [SQLite release notes](https://sqlite.org/releaselog/3_22_0.html), it is possible to append a database to an executable:

> The [Append VFS](https://sqlite.org/src/file/ext/misc/appendvfs.c) is a [VFS shim](http://www.sqlite.org/vfs.html#shim) that allows an SQLite database to be
>   appended to some other file. This allows (for example) a database to
>   be appended to an executable that then opens and reads the database.

How can I do that?

Comment: The information in the AppendVFS file is pretty straightforward. This is meant to be done at the C API level. If you're using a wrapper for SQLite, check with the provider to see if they implement this. Otherwise, you'll have to write the C code yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just load or link the extension into your application, and open the database with that VFS:

```
// append-test.c

#include <stdio.h>
#include <sqlite3.h>

int main()
{
    extern int sqlite3_appendvfs_init(sqlite3 *, char **, const sqlite3_api_routines *);
    sqlite3_appendvfs_init(NULL, NULL, NULL); // this works only if linked statically

    sqlite3 *db;
    sqlite3_open_v2("append-test", &db,
                    SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE | SQLITE_OPEN_CREATE,
                    "apndvfs");
    // error handling is for wimps

    sqlite3_exec(db, "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test(msg)", NULL, NULL, NULL);

    sqlite3_stmt *stmt;
    sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, "SELECT msg FROM test", -1, &stmt, NULL);

    switch (sqlite3_step(stmt)) {

    case SQLITE_DONE:
        sqlite3_exec(db, "INSERT INTO test VALUES('Hello, world!')", NULL, NULL, NULL);
        break;

    case SQLITE_ROW:
        puts(sqlite3_column_text(stmt, 0));
        break;
    }

    sqlite3_finalize(stmt);
    sqlite3_close(db);
    return 0;
}
```

When using static linking, [the extension must be compiled with `SQLITE_CORE`](http://www.sqlite.org/loadext.html#statically_linking_a_run_time_loadable_extension):

```
$ gcc -o append-test -D SQLITE_CORE append-test.c sqlite3.c appendvfs.c -lpthread -ldl
```

An executing executable cannot be written to, so run a copy:

```
$ ls -l
-rwxr-xr-x 1 cl users 901336 Jan 24 20:09 append-test
$ cp append-test append-test-2; append-test-2; rm append-test-2
$ ls -l
-rwxr-xr-x 1 cl users 913433 Jan 24 20:09 append-test
$ append-test
Hello, world!
```

In the real world, you would instead load the `appendvfs.dll`/`appendvfs.so` file into the `sqlite3` command-line shell with `.load`, and create the database in your application's executable file from there, manually or with a script.